# Why can't I install packages on an LTS release?

Tags: apt

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. This is supposed to be supported until April 2023. When I try to install a package with apt-get install libboost-all-dev, I get the output

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4
  404 Not Found [IP: 204.68.140.232 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4
  404 Not Found [IP: 204.68.140.232 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-dev_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 204.68.140.232 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-dev_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 204.68.140.232 80]
E: Aborting install
```

Google results tell me this error is because the release is no longer supported. But it should still be supported, shouldn't it? I've tried following the directions to update /etc/apt/sources.list to use old-releases, but I get similar output of 404 Not Found when doing apt-get update. And if I just try to run apt-get install libboost-all-dev after updating sources.list, it's unable to locate the package, probably because it needs to update, which it can't do.

Why can't I install this package on an LTS release which is still supposed to be supported?

Comment: Or switch to main server.

Answer (score 1):

Those packages are in the repositories, but you're trying to install obsolete versions that have been superseded and removed. That's why you are getting a 404 error.

Work backwards:

- You're getting apt 404 errors because your local database of packages is out of date. You update that database using `apt update`. For most folks, that's all they need to do.
- But your specific case is wierder: `apt update` is also giving you 404 errors.

  There are two possible causes:

  1. You are using a bad mirror. (change mirrors)
  2. Your network is blocking access to the mirror.

  Figure out which of those two is the culprit.

Comment: I mentioned I did apt-get update in my original comment and it gives the same 404 errors. apt update gives the same output as apt-get update, which is a bunch of 404 errors.

Comment: @Thundercleez yeah, you mentioned that as an afterthought so I assumed you understood how to troubleshoot it. Sorry, my mistake. Big edit to the answer to address your situation.